# Angularjs detecting routeChangeStart from directive inside a template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, directive, angularjs-ng-include

I've got a pretty standard directive that lives on an anchor element, which parses a string to see whether the current route matches that link, e.g.

```
<a href="/dashboard" data-nav-item="dashboard">Dashboard</a>
```

This directive runs each time the route changes (as the links can live outside of the ng-view which changes, so their state needs to be refreshed on a route change), using $routeChangeStart. This works fine within my main navigation, which lives within a standard view, but if I use this directive within an ng-included file (like my subnavigations), it fails to run any code inside the routeChangeStart callback. I've tried injecting $rootScope instead, but it makes no difference. The directive is as follows:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('navItem', ['$rootScope','$location', function ($rootScope, $location) {
   return {
       restrict: 'A',
       scope: false,
       link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
           console.log('All directive elements execute this!');
           $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
               console.log('ng-included elements work execute this!');
           });
       }
    }
}]);
```

How can I get access to this event from inside a directive within an ng-include template? The directive runs, but just won't pick this up.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I've been trying to recreate it on plunker but it works for me

http://plnkr.co/edit/9hbTLxGjoTNsM44zq6rw?p=preview

```
app.directive('navItem', ['$rootScope','$location', function ($rootScope, $location) {
   return {
       restrict: 'A',
       scope: false,
       link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
           console.log('All directive elements execute this!');
           $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
               console.log('ng-included elements work execute this!');
           });
       }
    }
}]);
```

check my plunker maybe you can find a difference between yours and mine code

Comment: Bizarre, will take another look today and see if I can spot any differences.